# Matlab App Designer doesn't open, outputs multiple errors

Tags: 12.04, matlab

I am trying to launch `Matlab App Designer`.

Using: Ubuntu 12.04 with 3.2 Kernel, Matlab version is 2016b

I have the following error:

```
Error in
appdesigner.internal.application.AppDesignerWindowController/bringToFront
(line 123)
            obj.BrowserController.bringToFront();

Error in
appdesigner.internal.application.AppDesignEnvironment/openApp
(line 161)
            obj.AppDesignerWindowController.bringToFront();

Error in
appdesigner.internal.application.AppDesignEnvironment/startAppDesigner
(line 68)
                obj.openApp(filePath);

Error in appdesigner (line 62)
appdesigner.internal.application.getAppDesignEnvironment().startAppDesigner(filePath);
```

How can I solve it?